# EF Core 5, Diferent convertions for the same property on subclassed entities

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class CabinetDevice : Device
    {
        public class CabinetData : DeviceData
        {
            public string Name1 { get; set; }
            public decimal Name2 { get; set; }
        }

        public CabinetData JsonData { get; set; }

        public CabinetDevice(long id) : base(id)
        {

        }
    }

    public class StationDevice : Device
    {
        public class StationData : DeviceData
        {
            public string Option1 { get; set; }
            public string Option2 { get; set; }
        }

        public StationData JsonData { get; set; }

        public StationDevice(long id) : base(id)
        {

        }
    }

    public class RelayDevice : Device
    {
        public class RelayData : DeviceData
        {
            public string Setting1 { get; set; }
            public string Setting2 { get; set; }
        }

        public RelayData JsonData { get; set; }

        public RelayDevice(long id) : base(id)
        {

        }
    }

    public abstract class Device : Entity<long>
    {
        public class DeviceData
        {

        }

        public Device(long id) : base(id)
        {

        }

        public Device(DeviceType deviceType, string serial, string name)
        {
            DeviceType = deviceType;
            Serial = serial;
            Name = name;
            Activate();
        }

        public Status Status { get; private set; }
        public DeviceType DeviceType { get; private set; }
        public string Serial { get; private set; }
        public string Group { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string IP { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string JsonConfig { get; private set; }
        public int RSSI { get; private set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; private set; }
        public DateTime DateLastSeen { get; private set; }
        public int BatteryVoltage { get; private set; }

        //public string JsonData { get; set; }

        public void Activate()
        {
            Status = Status.Active;
        }

        public void Inactivate()
        {
            Status = Status.Inactive;
        }

        public void UpdateJsonData(string json)
        {
            //JsonData = json;
        }

        public void UpdateJsonConfig(string json)
        {
            JsonConfig = json;
        }
    }
```

and :

```
   public class StationDeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StationDevice>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StationDevice> builder)
        {
            // This Converter will perform the conversion to and from Json to the desired type
            builder.Property(e => e.JsonData).HasJsonConversion();
        }
    }
    public class RelayDeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RelayDevice>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RelayDevice> builder)
        {
            // This Converter will perform the conversion to and from Json to the desired type
            builder.Property(e => e.JsonData).HasJsonConversion();
        }
    }
    public class CabinetDeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CabinetDevice>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CabinetDevice> builder)
        {
            // This Converter will perform the conversion to and from Json to the desired type
            builder.Property(e => e.JsonData).HasJsonConversion();
        }
    }

    public sealed class DeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Device> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(nameof(Device));

            builder.HasKey(device => device.Id);

            builder.Property(device => device.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn()
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.BatteryVoltage)
                .HasDefaultValue(0)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.DateCreated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.DateLastSeen)
                .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.MinValue)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.DateUpdated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.RSSI)
                .HasDefaultValue(0)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.Status)
                .HasDefaultValue(Status.None)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(s => s.DeviceType)
                .HasConversion<int>()
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasDiscriminator(p => p.DeviceType)
                .HasValue<StationDevice>(DeviceType.Station)
                .HasValue<RelayDevice>(DeviceType.Relay)
                .HasValue<CabinetDevice>(DeviceType.Cabinet);
        }
```

The migration

```
 partial class ContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.6")
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.Credential", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<long>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("bigint")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Login")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(100)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(100)");

                    b.Property<string>("Password")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(1000)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(1000)");

                    b.Property<int>("Roles")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Salt")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(1000)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(1000)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("Login")
                        .IsUnique();

                    b.ToTable("Credential");

                    b.HasData(
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 1L,
                            Login = "admin",
                            Password = "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",
                            Roles = 3,
                            Salt = "79005744-e69a-4b09-996b-08fe0b70cbb9"
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.Device", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<long>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("bigint")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:IdentityIncrement", 1)
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:IdentitySeed", 1)
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<int>("BatteryVoltage")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasDefaultValue(0);

                    b.Property<DateTime>("DateCreated")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("DateLastSeen")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                        .HasDefaultValue(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

                    b.Property<DateTime>("DateUpdated")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("DeviceType")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Group")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("IP")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("JsonConfig")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("RSSI")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasDefaultValue(0);

                    b.Property<string>("Serial")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("Status")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasDefaultValue(0);

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Device");

                    b.HasDiscriminator<int>("DeviceType");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<long>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("bigint")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<long>("CredentialId")
                        .HasColumnType("bigint");

                    b.Property<string>("Phone")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("Status")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("CredentialId")
                        .IsUnique();

                    b.ToTable("User");

                    b.HasData(
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 1L,
                            CredentialId = 1L,
                            Status = 1
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.CabinetDevice", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Architecture.Domain.Device");

                    b.Property<string>("JsonData")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");

                    b.HasDiscriminator().HasValue(2);

                    b.HasData(
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 4L,
                            DeviceType = 2,
                            Group = "Cabinets",
                            Name = "#1",
                            Serial = "a4",
                            JsonData = "{\r\n  \"name1\": \"123\",\r\n  \"name2\": 69\r\n}"
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.RelayDevice", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Architecture.Domain.Device");

                    b.Property<string>("JsonData")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
                        .HasColumnName("RelayDevice_JsonData");

                    b.HasDiscriminator().HasValue(1);

                    b.HasData(
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 5L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Outlets",
                            Name = "Picnic #1",
                            Serial = "relay-A8032ACE59C8",
                            JsonData = "{\r\n  \"setting1\": \"123\",\r\n  \"setting2\": \"123\"\r\n}"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 6L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Outlets",
                            Name = "Picnic #2",
                            Serial = "a6"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 7L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Lights",
                            Name = "Picnic #1",
                            Serial = "a7"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 8L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Lights",
                            Name = "Picnic #2",
                            Serial = "a8"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 9L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Lights",
                            Name = "Farola #1",
                            Serial = "a9"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 10L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Lights",
                            Name = "Farola #2",
                            Serial = "a10"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 11L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Keys",
                            Name = "Entrada",
                            Serial = "a11"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 12L,
                            DeviceType = 1,
                            Group = "Keys",
                            Name = "Baño",
                            Serial = "a12"
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.StationDevice", b =>
                {
                    b.HasBaseType("Architecture.Domain.Device");

                    b.Property<string>("JsonData")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
                        .HasColumnName("StationDevice_JsonData");

                    b.HasDiscriminator().HasValue(0);

                    b.HasData(
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 1L,
                            DeviceType = 0,
                            Group = "Stations",
                            Name = "#1",
                            Serial = "a1",
                            JsonData = "{\r\n  \"option1\": \"123\",\r\n  \"option2\": \"teo\"\r\n}"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 2L,
                            DeviceType = 0,
                            Group = "Stations",
                            Name = "#2",
                            Serial = "a2"
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            Id = 3L,
                            DeviceType = 0,
                            Group = "Stations",
                            Name = "#3",
                            Serial = "a3"
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Architecture.Domain.User", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Architecture.Domain.Credential", "Credential")
                        .WithOne()
                        .HasForeignKey("Architecture.Domain.User", "CredentialId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.OwnsOne("Architecture.Domain.Email", "Email", b1 =>
                        {
                            b1.Property<long>("UserId")
                                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                                .HasColumnType("bigint")
                                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                            b1.Property<string>("Value")
                                .IsRequired()
                                .HasMaxLength(300)
                                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(300)")
                                .HasColumnName("Email");

                            b1.HasKey("UserId");

                            b1.HasIndex("Value")
                                .IsUnique()
                                .HasFilter("[Email] IS NOT NULL");

                            b1.ToTable("User");

                            b1.WithOwner()
                                .HasForeignKey("UserId");

                            b1.HasData(
                                new
                                {
                                    UserId = 1L,
                                    Value = "administrator@administrator.com"
                                });
                        });

                    b.OwnsOne("Architecture.Domain.Name", "Name", b1 =>
                        {
                            b1.Property<long>("UserId")
                                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                                .HasColumnType("bigint")
                                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                            b1.Property<string>("FirstName")
                                .IsRequired()
                                .HasMaxLength(100)
                                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(100)")
                                .HasColumnName("FirstName");

                            b1.Property<string>("LastName")
                                .IsRequired()
                                .HasMaxLength(200)
                                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(200)")
                                .HasColumnName("LastName");

                            b1.HasKey("UserId");

                            b1.ToTable("User");

                            b1.WithOwner()
                                .HasForeignKey("UserId");

                            b1.HasData(
                                new
                                {
                                    UserId = 1L,
                                    FirstName = "Administrator",
                                    LastName = "Administrator"
                                });
                        });

                    b.Navigation("Credential");

                    b.Navigation("Email");

                    b.Navigation("Name");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
```

And the seed:

```
 private static void SeedDevices(this ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<StationDevice>(device =>
            {
                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 1L,
                    Serial = "a1",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Station,
                    Name = "#1",
                    Group = "Stations",
                    JsonData = new StationDevice.StationData() { Option1 = "123", Option2 = "teo" }
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 2L,
                    Serial = "a2",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Station,
                    Name = "#2",
                    Group = "Stations"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 3L,
                    Serial = "a3",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Station,
                    Name = "#3",
                    Group = "Stations"
                });
            });

            builder.Entity<CabinetDevice>(device =>
            {
                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 4L,
                    Serial = "a4",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Cabinet,
                    Name = "#1",
                    Group = "Cabinets",
                    JsonData = new CabinetDevice.CabinetData() { Name1 = "123", Name2 = 69 }
                });
            });

            builder.Entity<RelayDevice>(device =>
            {
                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 5L,
                    Serial = "relay-A8032ACE59C8",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Picnic #1",
                    Group = "Outlets",
                    JsonData = new RelayDevice.RelayData() { Setting1 = "123", Setting2 = "123" }
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 6L,
                    Serial = "a6",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Picnic #2",
                    Group = "Outlets"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 7L,
                    Serial = "a7",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Picnic #1",
                    Group = "Lights"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 8L,
                    Serial = "a8",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Picnic #2",
                    Group = "Lights"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 9L,
                    Serial = "a9",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Farola #1",
                    Group = "Lights"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 10L,
                    Serial = "a10",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Farola #2",
                    Group = "Lights"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 11L,
                    Serial = "a11",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Entrada",
                    Group = "Keys"
                });

                device.HasData(new
                {
                    Id = 12L,
                    Serial = "a12",
                    DeviceType = DeviceType.Relay,
                    Name = "Baño",
                    Group = "Keys"
                });
            });
        }
```

The json converter

```
public static class ValueConversionExtensions
    {
        public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder) where T : class, new()
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                WriteIndented = true,
                AllowTrailingCommas = true,
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };

            ValueConverter<T, string> converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>
            (
                v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options),
                v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(v, options) ?? new T()
            );

            ValueComparer<T> comparer = new ValueComparer<T>
            (
                (l, r) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(l, options) == JsonSerializer.Serialize(r, options),
                v => v == null ? 0 : JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options).GetHashCode(),
                v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options), options)
            );

            propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
            propertyBuilder.HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");

            return propertyBuilder;
        }
    }
```

I want to store a json string in a common field JsonData for all subclasses and convert to different clases depending on the the entity, I almost got there :

[image]

It's creating 3 different fields, one for each subclass, The first one got it right but on the following classes its creating additional rows RelayDevice_JsonData and StationDevice_JsonData

Comment: IMHO don't map the subclass properties, just cast from the base type; `[NotMapped] public CabinetData JsonData { get => (CabinetData)base.JsonObj; set => base.JsonObj=value; }`

Comment: The problem is that I'm using 3 different converters, one for each subclass